# SQL Server: error converting data type varchar to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, runtime-error, numeric, varchar

Here is the situation.  I have a SQL Server table that contains the following columns:

```
TaskOrder (varchar(50), null)
Labor (decimal(18,2), null)
LaborCLIN (varchar(50), null)
```

I am creating a stored procedure that passes in the parameter: `@TaskOrder`

I created a temp table as follows:

```
declare @miprfin table
(
    TaskOdr varchar(50),
    Labor decimal(18,2),
    LaborClin varchar(50)
)
```

When I run the following query:

```
insert into @miprfin
   select TaskOrder, LaborCLIN, sum(labor) as labor
   from MIPRFIN 
   where TaskOrder = @TaskOrder
   group by TaskOrder, LaborCLIN
   order by LaborCLIN
```

I get the following error message:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 404
>   Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

I do not see where it is trying to convert any data.

I am using SQL Server 2012 Management Studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always put the columns in an `insert`, and this is why:

```
insert into @miprfin(TaskOdr, LaborCLIN, Labor)
    select TaskOrder, LaborCLIN, sum(labor) as labor
    from MIPRFIN 
    where TaskOrder = @TaskOrder
    group by TaskOrder, LaborCLIN
    order by LaborCLIN;
```

You were putting `labor` into the `laborclin` field and vice versa.  Hence the error.

Comment: Thank you very much.  That worked out great.  I have been beating my head on this for two days.